# Ruby on Rails multi table queries through forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***Note: Please refer to this link for the updated question. I've rephrased my question to be more concise after trying sometime else: [Ruby on Rails single form to update multiple records using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900349/ruby-on-rails-single-form-to-update-multiple-records-using-loop)***

I have a page to show all the bidders for a particular project and the bidders.html.erb is as follows:

```html
<div id="titlebar" class="single submit-page">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Bidders</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-lg-2">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Find Assignments
      </button>
    </div>
    -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Table -->
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="margin-bottom-25"> Bids can be viewed or removed below.</p>

    <table class="manage-table resumes responsive-table">

      <tr>

        <th><i class="fa fa-genderless"></i> Gender</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Experience</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> Education Level</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Expected Salary</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Status</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <!-- Item #1 -->

        <tbody>
    <% @bidders.each do |bidder| %>
      <tr>
        <% if bidder.gender == 1 %>
          <td>Male</td>
        <% else %>
          <td>Female</td>
        <% end %>

        <td><%= bidder.experience %></td>
        <td><%= bidder.education.education %></td>
        <td><%= bidder.expected_salary %></td>
        <td><%= bidder.bid.status %></td>
        <td class="action">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide</a>
          <a href="#" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Item #1 -->
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

And my application_controller.rb is:

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  
  def bidders
    bidders_ids = Bid.where(bidders_params).pluck(:user_id)
    @bidders = User.where(id: bidders_ids)
  end
  
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    assignments_path #your path
  end

end
```

The database design more or less is depicted by the following:

[image]

The issue is that I need help with converting the bidders.html.erb script to a form to allow the owner of the particular project to accepts and rank multiple bidders by editing the bidder.bid.status to ranking numbers.

Do note that users can be bidders and can also create projects for others to bid on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that has a problem of the modeling in your application

Maybe this way should be better.

user.rb

```
def class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :bids, class_name: 'Bid', :foreign_key => "user_iduser"
end
```

# controller.rb

```
def bidders
  @user = User.find(params[id)
end
```

# in view

```
<% @user.bids.each do |bidder| %>
  <tr>
    <% if bidder.gender == 1 %>
      <td>Male</td>
    <% else %>
      <td>Female</td>
    <% end %>

    <td><%= bidder.experience %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.education.education %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.expected_salary %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.bid.status %></td>
    <td class="action">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide</a>
      <a href="#" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!-- Item #1 -->
<% end %>
```

analysing your database design and it looks like you want a association `has_many :through`, more info here in [guides rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

You’ll need to looking more info about nested forms http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: I think this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900349/ruby-on-rails-single-form-to-update-multiple-records-using-loop
better represents my question