# Ruby on Rails single form to update multiple records using loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code that loop through each bidder and tries to create an input box for the owner of the assignment to update the status of the particular bid by each particular bidder.

```html
<div id="titlebar" class="single submit-page">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Bidders</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-lg-2">
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Find Assignments
      </button>
    </div>
    -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Table -->
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="margin-bottom-25"> Bids can be viewed or removed below.</p>

    <table class="manage-table resumes responsive-table">

      <tr>

        <th><i class="fa fa-genderless"></i> Gender</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Experience</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> Education Level</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Expected Salary</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Status</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <!-- Item #1 -->
      
      <tbody>
        <% @bidders.each_with_index do |bidder, i| %>
          <tr>
          <% if bidder.gender == 1 %>
            <td>Male</td>
          <% else %>
            <td>Female</td>
          <% end %>

          <td><%= bidder.experience %></td>
          <td><%= bidder.education.education %></td>
          <td><%= bidder.expected_salary %></td>
          <td><%= bidder.bid.status %></td>
          <%= form_for(@bids[i]) do |f| %>
            <td><%= f.label :status %> and <%= f.text_field :status %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td class="action">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide</a>
            <a href="#" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Item #1 -->
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
      
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

application_controller.rb:

```
def bidders
  bidders_ids = Bid.where(bidders_params).pluck(:user_id)
  @bidders = User.where(id: bidders_ids)
  @bids = Bid.where(bidders_params)
end
```

bids_controller.rb:

```
  def bid_params
    params.require(:bid).permit(:status, :assignment_id, :user_id)
    #params.permit(:status, :assignment_id, :user_id)
  end
```

The problem is that the loop creates multiple forms.

1. I want only one form but multiple Dropdown Select option 1..x depending on the total number of bidders on this particular assignment for ranking purposes.
2. I want to ensure that once I click on the submit button (which I haven't include), all the multiple :status fields to be updated in the database in their respective records.

Comment: Do you need something like x-editable [demo link](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html)

Comment: https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

x-editable will create a form with remote-true for each attributes do you want to change

[image]

Comment: Yes something like that. But I'll need it to be linked to the database. In other words, this form has to be submitted and updated to the table. How can I do that?

Comment: please for more info http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Comment: Thanks! Looks like something I'm looking for. I'll try it!

Comment: @BrenoPerruchi I'll also need to edit multiple instances in a single form with this gem's features. Is that possible? (I.e. Edit multiple user profiles instead of just one in a single form)

Comment: If your will list this profiles in the same page like html table than you will can editting multiple users

Comment: Is this image has 4 objects of class Unit and I can change all in the same page.